# What is Leta Lestrange afraid of in Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

[Boggart](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/boggarts) takes the shape of the thing the viewer is afraid of.

> Boggarts lurk in cupboards and when confronted, take the form of your worst fears.

In *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, when Leta Lestrange faces the boggart, it takes shape of some white cloth floating. That scene moves and it doesn't get cleared what is it and why she fears it.

So, **is there any explanation what exactly that thing was and why she fears it?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The scene/fear is explained near the end of the film.

When Leta is explaining her trip to the US with her baby brother constantly crying and screaming, she exchanges the crying baby with a silent sleeping baby.  The ship then sinks and the original baby sinks to the depths of the ocean in a white sheet moving just as her Boggart experience.

Comment: Oh. I must've missed that sinking scene.

Comment: My understanding was that she was afraid somebody would find out about it. Dumbledore must have sensed it was something like that because he ended her stint with the boggart early.

Answer (score -1):

The scene shortly after that when Leta is talking to Dumbledore, she asked him if he thinks she is bad, and then they get talking a little, and that's where he says it was his sister he lost. Although the 1st time watching it, the scene is not too clear and obviously nobody would guess what her fear was with the Bogart at first.